# calling the indexed position of a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

so I'm writing a small program as part of something larger to pull a name out of a file path.  The name in question is always going to start at the same spot in the file path, so my reasoning was something like this to get the name i wanted.

Say the Path was something like this C:/Docs/Bob/blah/blah/blah

```
#cut the string at to the beginning of the name
path = path[8:]
#make a loop to iterate over the string
for letter in path:
    if(letter == '/'):
        string_index = index

return path[:string_index]
```

what I am looking for is a way to get that "index"

Thanks!

Comment: Read the ```enumerate``` help.

Comment: Which `/` are you trying to get the index of? There are many.

Comment: the string cuts itself, so it starts at Bob/blah... I'm trying to cut out everything but "Bob"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.  Use `os.path` instead.  For instance:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> path = 'C:\\Docs\\Bob\\blah\\blah\\blah'
>>> base = 'C:\\Docs'
>>> os.path.relpath(path, base)
'Bob\\blah\\blah\\blah'
```

Also, using `os.path` will ensure that your code will work on other platforms, not just Windows (assuming the base path is set correctly).

If you just want `'Bob'` as the answer, then you probably want to do something like

```
>>> import re
>>> # Windows supports both / and \
>>> if os.path.altsep:
...     sep=os.path.sep + os.path.altsep
... else:
...     sep=os.path.sep
...
>>> pseps = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(sep))
>>> pseps.split(os.path.relpath(path,base), 1)[0]
'Bob'
```

(Sadly `os.path.split()` only works from the *rightmost* end, so we can't easily use it here without recursing.)